# Difference between WebDriver and FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am completely new to Selenium WebDriver. Can anyone please tell me what is the difference 
between these two lines?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and

```
FirefoxDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Both launch the Firefox browser. So Why we always write the first line instead of 2nd line?

Comment: Not a Selenium specific question, it's just Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebDriver is an interface.

FirefoxDriver is the implementation.

To understand better, please do read docs on Java Interface.

Answer (score 4):

This is what is called "Static and Dynamic Binding in Java".

You can google it with above words, you will get hell lot of sites.

To tell you in simple terms:

```
class vehicle
{
 public void print(String str)
 { System.out.println("I am string "+str);}

 public void print(Integer int)
 {System.out.println("I am integer:"+int);}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  vehicle obj=new vehicle();
  obj.print("Hello"); //Then it is clear that it will call first print method i.e String
 } //This is method overloading.
}
```

This is decided at compile time. so Static binding.

The other case is:

```
class vehicle
{
 void start(){System.out.println("Vehicle started");}
}
class car extends vehicle
{
 void start(){System.out.println("Car started");}
}
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  vehicle obj=new car();
  obj.start(); //Here it prints Car's start method and is decided at run time so dynamic binding
 }
}

} //This is method overriding
```

As per your question:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()   //This is dynamic binding
FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()  //Kind of static binding
```

Comment: Not that you are wrong, but SO isnt a tutorial site, which is why the correct answer is like the other one is which is "go read the java documentation on interfaces" and probably inheritance.

Comment: The user might unaware the actual concept why the behavior. So i told him the concept as "Static and Dynamic Binding" and also asked him to refer other sites. To give him some overview, i explained him that concept. I hope you understand my intent. Thanks.