# Why do you are creating object of interface in selenium webDriver?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Difference between

```
WebDriver wb=new FirefoxDriver();
FirefoxDriver fd=new FirefoxDriver();
```

which one is more suitable for selenium webdriver?

Comment: You answered your own question: "selenium webdriver".

Comment: No clue what you are asking here.  Please restate you question better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between WebDriver and FirefoxDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719556/difference-between-webdriver-and-firefoxdriver)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver vs ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378442/webdriver-vs-chromedriver)

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757034/why-we-assign-firefoxdriver-instance-to-webdriver

Comment: @KirilS. The above ^^ link doesn't speaks about `FirefoxDriver fd=new FirefoxDriver();` as asked in this Question. Please go through the QA/Discussion properly before marking as duplicate to them.

Comment: @DebanjanB which of the above links? there's 3. And both marked as "possible duplicate" talk exactly about the same topic. Or you cannot generalize answer about Chrome to Firefox?

Comment: its not bound to selenium, its a general problem of why to declare a variable more abstract than the implementation. in most pragmatic cases..., makes no sence. Interfaces are more for frameworks when the implementation can be of another type. otherwize its just theoretically better without benefit